# Xamarin - Java.Lang.RuntimeException just after deploy

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on login page to android application. Right now I've two Activities:
[image: Activities in project]

If I set `MainLauncher = true` on MainActivity.cs app deploy with succes. When I set `MainLauncher = true` to LoginActivity.cs I get:

`Java.Lang.RuntimeException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`
in output console and in messege box:

[image]

My LoginActivity.cs code is:

```
[Activity(Label = "Login Page", MainLauncher = true)]
public class LoginActivity : Activity
{
    private EditText editTextLogin;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;

    public LoginActivity()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Locked;

        editTextLogin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextLogin);
        editTextPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonLogin);

        buttonLogin.Click += OnButtonLoginClick;
    }

    private void HockeyAppInit()
    {
        CrashManager.Register(this, HOCKEYAPP_APPID);
        UpdateManager.Register(this, HOCKEYAPP_APPID);
    }

    private void OnButtonLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // first tests
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }

  }
```

And layout located in \Resources\layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/favicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextLogin"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="Zaloguj" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you hit `Continue` until the debugging session exits when running into this unhandled exception, there should be more logging in the `Output`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After copy-pasting your provided code into a blank new Android project, everything is working as expected even with `MainLauncher = true`, excluding the `favicon`.

Ensure sure you have a `favicon.png` image inside the `drawable` folder and its **Build Action** is set to `AndroidResource`.

If that doesn't help, I would suggest cleaning the solution and also manually deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project folder to make sure there are no conflicting temporary files left behind. Also uninstall the app from your emulator / device completely.

Comment: Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders worked peerfectly!

Comment: Awesome!! Glad to help :-) . Wish you happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and there was nothing wrong with my XML files also no issue in my Activity Classes so I resolved this issue by

1. Cleaning the solution and rebuilding app
2. If this does not resolve your issue, please delete Debug and Release folders under bin and rebuild solution again.

Hope this will resolve your this issue.